# Protected variable in main method

Tags: java, variables

I declared my local variable to protected that is the same name with other general variable.

My code:

```
public class jc8 {

  private int x = 8;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    protected int x = 5;               // compile time ERROR
  }
}
```

why ?

Comment: What does `protected` modifier do?

Comment: @RohitJain It is a exam question.

Comment: Why indeed? It isn't legal Java. I find it hard to believe that this is an exam question in exactly this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `protected` key word inside a method block. This is to modify the `access` of `members`, not of `local variables`. Think about it. your local variable's scope is only the main method. It is, by definition, private to that method.

**Example**

```
protected int x = 10;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Valid
}
```

This will allow subclasses of your class to have access to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

"public", "protected" or "private" are visibility modifiers that can be applied to class members not to local variables.

But more important than that, what do you try to accomplish with this definition?, what its the meaning in your head of a local variable to be protected?, think about this and try to understand "why" this is not possible in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
o   Protected Accessibilty:
    Indicates that a member can be accessed from any class in the same package and from the child classes from other packages. A keyword “protected” is used to represent protected accessibility before the data type of a member declaration.
Example:
protected int y;
protected void method(){}
```

so you can not use protected inside a block of code .you need to declare it outside of block of code 
you declared

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    protected int x = 5;               // compile time ERROR
  }
```

Right way is

```
protected int x = 5; 
 public static void main(String[] args) {

                  // compile time ERROR
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable not modified.
Why your are trying to do it?

Their scope is between method braces.